# Simple Calculation Confusion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I don't understand how did it go from left hand side to the right hand side for this equation: 
$$
\sum_{r=n}^{\infty}[\frac{\lambda(\lambda t)^{r-1}e^{-\lambda t}}{(r-1)!} - \frac{\lambda(\lambda t)^re^{-\lambda t}}{r!}] = \frac{\lambda(\lambda t)^{n-1}e^{-\lambda t}}{(n-1)!}
$$

How I did(and got stuck):
$$
\sum_{r=n}^{\infty}[\frac{\lambda(\lambda t)^{r-1}e^{-\lambda t}}{(r-1)!} - \frac{\lambda(\lambda t)^re^{-\lambda t}}{r!}] = \lambda e^{-\lambda t} \sum_{r=n}^{\infty}\frac{(\lambda t)^{r-1} (r-\lambda t)}{r!}
$$

This is Example 5.2 of the book Stochastic Processes: An Introduction by P.W. Jones and P.Smith, 3rd edition.

The entire Example + Solution is as follows:

Example 5.2 Incoming telephone calls to an operator are assumed to be a Poisson process with parameter λ. Find the density function of the length of time for n calls to be received, and find the mean time and variance of the random variable of the length of time for $n$ calls.

We are now interested in the time $T_n$, which is the earliest time at which the random variable $N(t) = n$ occurs, and its distribution. The probability distribution of the random variable Tn is given by

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
F(t) &= P\{T_n≤t\} \\
    &= P\{\text{n or more calls have arrived in the time interval} (0, t)\} \\
&= p_n(t)+p_{n+1}(t)+ ···\\
&= \sum^{∞}_{r=n} p_r(t) \\
&= \sum^{∞}_{r=n} \frac{(λt)^r e^{−λt}}{r!}
\end{split}
\end{equation}$

using (5.1). The corresponding density function is

$$
f(t)=\frac{dF(t)}{dt}=\sum_{r=n}^{\infty}[\frac{\lambda(\lambda t)^{r-1}e^{-\lambda t}}{(r-1)!} - \frac{\lambda(\lambda t)^re^{-\lambda t}}{r!}] = \frac{\lambda(\lambda t)^{n-1}e^{-\lambda t}}{(n-1)!}
$$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the r.h.s. of  your formula has denominator  $(r-1)!$ – $r is here a dummy variable.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you! I have edited the type-o in my post.

Comment: The sum telescopes.

Comment: @user58697 I was thinking about it too but the sum starts from n, not 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite the sum as

$$
\sum_{r=n}^{\infty}[\frac{\lambda(\lambda t)^{r-1}e^{-\lambda t}}{(r-1)!} - 
\frac{\lambda(\lambda t)^re^{-\lambda t}}{r!}] = 
\sum_{r=n}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda(\lambda t)^{r-1}e^{-\lambda t}}{(r-1)!} - 
\sum_{r=n}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda(\lambda t)^re^{-\lambda t}}{r!}$$

(it is absolutely convergent, so the rearrangement is legal).

Observe that the first sum is

$$
\sum_{r=n}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda(\lambda t)^{r-1}e^{-\lambda t}}{(r-1)!} =
\sum_{r=n-1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda(\lambda t)^{r}e^{-\lambda t}}{(r)!} =
\frac{\lambda(\lambda t)^{n-1}e^{-\lambda t}}{(n-1)!} +
\sum_{r=n}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda(\lambda t)^{r}e^{-\lambda t}}{(r)!}
$$

So both infinite summations are identical and cancel each out.